# Can I use different prettier options for `<script>` and `<style>` tag in a `.vue` file?

Tags: vue.js, prettier

Such as:

1. Can I disable prettier only for `<script>` or `<style>` tag in a `.vue` file?
2. Can I use different prettier options for `<script>` and `<style>` tag in a `.vue` file?

I want to use different prettier options for `<script>` and `<style>` tag in a `.vue` file.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is the Vetur VSCode plugin. It allows you to choose different formatters depending on language.
Just install the extension, then go to Settings and search "Vetur formatter", there you can choose your favorite plugin to format each part of your vue file.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm using Vue3 and the Volar VSCode extension, but Volar doesn't provide this config options. Should I use Volar and Vetur together?